# push object in the heap using pointer to the static container

Tags: c++, static, stl, stack

```
class Node_Str{
public:
string name;
string value;
string type;
Node_Str(string name,string value,string type){
name=name;
value=value;
type=type;}};    

static stack<Node_Str> s;
void find_token(string input){
int cursor=0;
string current="";
while(cursor<input.length()){
char value;
value=input[cursor];
cout<<value<<endl;
if(value=='('||value==')'||value=='+'||value=='-
'||value=='*'||value=='/'){
Node_Str* p=new Node_Str("pare",string(1,value),"Pare");
s.push(*p);
cursor++;
delete p;}
if(value==' '){
cursor++;
}
if(value=='1'||value=='2'||value=='3'||value=='4'){
Node_Str* p=new Node_Str("num",string(1,value),"Number");
s.push(*p);
cursor++;
delete p;}}}
int main(){
while(!s.empty()){
cout<<s.top().value<<" ";
s.pop();   }
return 0; }
```

The find_token function should separate the input string by  white Space and constructing the `Node_Str` object with the value of that string. Then in the 
main function, I would like to print it. The characters are limit. Just '1', '2','3','4','+,'-','*','/'.
Input is 4 + 4 , output should be 4+4. However, there is no output.

Comment: You have not deleted the memory allocated using new int, that's memory leak

Comment: May be you forgot to call `find()`

Comment: *The program can run with no error or memory leak.* That claim is wrong. You are leaking memory. You are allocating memory uisng `new int(i)` but there is no code to deallocate that memory.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Read documentation of every [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and other function before using them.

Comment: Do you mean that if I delete the pointer then I can get correct output? What's more, I am sure that main() function return 0.

Answer (score 0):

The comments already said about memory leak and forgetting to call find.

In addition to that, stack is a container in which to last to be pushed in would be the first to be popped out. In order to output 0 1 2 3, you would need to push in the stack in the sequence of 3 2 1 0.

Just giving a better version.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using std::cout;
using std::stack;

static stack<int> s;

void find()
{
    int* p;
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
        p = new int(i);
        s.push(*p);
        delete p; // p itself does not have to be returned so it can be safely deleted here
        //This can also ne replaced by directly using s.push(i)
    }
}

int main() {
    find();
    while (!s.empty()) 
    {
        cout << s.top() << " ";
        s.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by leyanpan, data should be pushed into reverse order, to get the desired output. One more point is no need of dynamic allocation for int type. It is always better to store non  array built in types in stack rather than heap.
Also allocating stack data structure as static variable will extend scope up to program termination. Better to use stack object as a local variable in main and pass it as are reference argument to function find.

Comment: That's true. Now I get the problem when I use stack to store the objects of the class defined by myself. stack.top() should return the object, however I can not use stack.top()->name. The "name " is a public variable of my class.